# Bootstrap modal - close modal when "call to action" button is clicked

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a external link inside my modal, and I want the modal to hide after the user has clicked on the link. How do I do that?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="modalwindow">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>You need to do a search on google.com for that.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a id="closemodal" href="https://www.google.com" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Launch google.com</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#closemodal').modal('hide');
</script>
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You need to bind the modal hide call to the `onclick` event.

Assuming you are using jQuery you can do that with:

```
$('#closemodal').click(function() {
    $('#modalwindow').modal('hide');
});
```

Also make sure the click event is bound after the document has finished loading:

```
$(function() {
   // Place the above code inside this block
});
enter code here
```

Comment: `modal` is attached to a jQuery object, so you need to call `$('.modal').modal()`

Comment: Well pointed. Fixing. Although I gotta say Kumar's answer is much more elegant.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Needed to change $('#closemodal').modal('hide'); to $('#modalwindow').modal('hide'); to make it work.

Comment: This is jquery and not vanilla javascript?

Comment: @webNoob13 Good point, yes its a solution with jQuery. Back in the day when this was answered, jQuery was so popular with Bootstrap it was kinda assumed you would always use it with it. I'll update the answer to be more explicit on this.

Answer (score 17):

**Remove your script, and change the HTML:**

```
<a id="closemodal" href="https://www.google.com" class="btn btn-primary close" data-dismiss="modal" target="_blank">Launch google.com</a>
```

EDIT: Please note that currently this will not work as this functionality does not yet exist in bootstrap. [See issue here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7192).

Comment: Yes, this closes the modal, but the new target link does not open.

Comment: If it's an external link, surely it doesn't matter if the modal closes or not, as the page will reload?

Comment: The target is "_blank", a new window opens, and the "old" window with the modal stays the same.

Comment: This doesn't work. Links inside a modal that use data-dismiss="modal" do not go not go to their destination. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7192

Comment: @LouiseEggleton This answer is too old. Anyways, what should I make it to correct, so that you can remove my downvote as well as my answer becomes right?

Comment: It's not too old. First the answer was wrong then and it's wrong now. I downvoted because your answer just does not work,yet people who stop by from Google may see it and try it and waste their time. As I stated in my other comment. "Links inside a modal that use data-dismiss="modal" do not go not go to their destination." Go to the link to see that it is a known issue. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7192 The correct anwser is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use `data-dismiss="modal"`.   In the version of Bootstrap I am using v3.3.5,  when  `data-dismiss="modal"` is added to the desired button like shown below it calls my external Javascript (JQuery) function beautifully and magically closes the modal. Its soo Sweet, I was worried I would have to call some modal hide in another function and chain that to the real working function

```
 <a href="#" id="btnReleaseAll" class="btn btn-primary btn-default btn-small margin-right pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</a>
```

In some external script file, and in my doc ready there is of course a function for the click of that identifier ID

```
 $("#divExamListHeader").on('click', '#btnReleaseAll', function () {
               // Do DatabaseMagic Here for a call a MVC ActionResult
```

Answer (score 0):

Make as shown.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');

    $('#myBtn').on('click', function(){
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
    
  });
<br/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried closing a modal window with a bootstrap CSS loaded. The close () method does not really close the modal window. So I added the display style to "none".

```
    function closeDialog() {
        let d = document.getElementById('d')
        d.style.display = "none"
        d.close()
    }
```

The HTML code includes a button into the dialog window.

```
<input type="submit" value="Confirm" onclick="closeDialog()"/>
```

Edit: Replace #closemodal by #modalwindow

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#closemodal').click(function(e) {
       $('#modalwindow').modal('hide');
    }
</script>
```